# Loopback Passport user is null

Tags: node.js, passport.js, loopbackjs

So I'm trying to do a basic Facebook integration with Loopback and Passport, using the example app as a guide:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport

I think I'm missing one minor thing because the `req.user` is always coming back as null even though everything else seems to line up.  This causes the `ensureLoggedIn(/failedLogin)` to direct to failed login every time.

Here's my `server.js`:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

// Creating a bit of passport
var PassportConfigurator = require('loopback-component-passport').PassportConfigurator;
var passportConfigurator = new PassportConfigurator(app);

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});

// Load the provider configurations
var config = {};
try {
  config = require('./providers.json');
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Please configure your passport strategy in `providers.json`.');
  console.error('Copy `providers.json.template` to `providers.json` and replace the clientID/clientSecret values with your own.');
  process.exit(1);
}

// to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.middleware('parse', bodyParser.json());
// to support URL-encoded bodies
app.middleware('parse', bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// The access token is only available after boot
app.middleware('auth', loopback.token({
  model: app.models.accessToken
}));

app.middleware('session:before', loopback.cookieParser(app.get('cookieSecret')));
app.middleware('session', loopback.session({
  secret: 'kitty',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

// We need flash messages to see passport errors
app.use(flash());

// Initialize passport
passportConfigurator.init();

// Set up related models
passportConfigurator.setupModels({
  userModel: app.models.Participant,
  userIdentityModel: app.models.userIdentity,
  userCredentialModel: app.models.userCredential
});
// Configure passport strategies for third party auth providers
for (var s in config) {
  var c = config[s];
  c.session = c.session !== false;
  passportConfigurator.configureProvider(s, c);
}

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// start the server if `$ node server.js`
if (require.main === module) {
  app.start();
}
```

And the `routes.js`:

```
var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn;

module.exports = function(app) {
  // Install a "/ping" route that returns "pong"
  app.get('/loginFail', function(req, res) {
    console.dir(req);
    res.send(req.sessionID);
  });

  app.get('/auth/account', ensureLoggedIn('/loginFail'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('logged IN!');
    console.dir(req);
    res.send(req.session);
  });

  app.get('/auth/logout', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('logging out');
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

By looking at the req object, I can see that there's a proper accessToken and it does match an access token in my database (in memory).

Currently I get a redirect on `/auth/account` to go to `/loginFail`.  The session is pretty bare but does exist.  The sessionID also exists.

Any insight as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out my issue.  What I did to solve it was clone the example and then go through with a fine tooth comb to see what the differences were.

It came down to the fact that I didn't add the models that were needed into the model-config.json:

```
"user": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": true
},
"accessToken": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
},
"userCredential": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
},
"userIdentity": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
},
"ACL": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
},
"RoleMapping": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
},
"Role": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
}
```

I was missing the `ACL`, `RoleMapping`, and `Role`.  They are all built in but need to be saved in the DB (durr).

Just hoping this helps someone else.